# Loading mswsock.dll takes too much time

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, windows-7

Everytime I run my application, loading time is too long.

So I looked output window, this was the reason. This take too much time.

'AppName.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mswsock.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file

I'm using VisualStudio 2010 rightnow, but it was ok with VisualStudio 2005.

64bit, 32bit doesn't matter. I tested on both system, all slow.

Can anyone give me any idea?

Comment: what is AppName.exe doing with the dll ? was it initiating a connection upon execution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are running your program under the Visual Studio debugger and you have the debugger set to automatically (try to) load debug symbols from Microsoft's symbol server.

When symbols for a DLL cannot be found locally or on the symbol server there is a long delay while Visual Studio works it out. Who knows why it takes so long, and why VS does not cache the fact there is no symbol available (to at least avoid checking every single time), but that's how it is.

Still, debug symbols are very useful and available for most system DLLs. Rather than turn off the symbol server completely, I find it best to make it only load symbols on demand. That way when you need them for a module you can right-click it (e.g. in a stack trace window) and tell VS to find the symbols for it.

You can do this under **Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Symbols** by changing **Automatically load symbols for** to **Only specified modules**. (For modules you want the symbols to often, you can add them to the list so you don't have to keep manually pulling them in.)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you've got a slow or malfunctioning Internet connection.  Tools + Options, Debugging, Symbols, untick "Microsoft Symbol Servers".

Comment: I disconnected the LAN cable and tried but still slow. I'll try with no symbol servers. thx.

Comment: Well, that's it then.  Use the advice.